# Add slash to redirect if URL is not ending with slash in Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, trailing-slash

I wanted to add a slash to a redirect URL because the target (Wordpress) also redirects if the url does not end with a slash. This would result in two redirects.

My current config doesn't seem to work

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name old.domain.com;

  location ~ ^(.*)[/]$ {
    return 302 https://new.domain.com/$request_uri;
  }

  location ~ ^(.*)[^/]$ {
    return 302 https://new.domain.com/$request_uri/;
  }
```

}

Comment: try to put url with '/'  before without '/' @StephanSchmidt,  might it matching with first without slash and redirecting it

Comment: Could you add this as an answer?

Comment: added as answer @StephanSchmidt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put url with '/' before without '/', might it matching with first without slash and redirecting it

Try this

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name old.domain.com;

  location ~ ^(.*)[/]$ {
    return 302 https://new.domain.com/$request_uri/;
  }

  location ~ ^(.*)[^/]$ {
    return 302 https://new.domain.com/$request_uri;
  }
```